# Equal Shape: Recovering an Isomorphism Between $M_{3\times 2}(F)$ and $P_5(F)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces

I'm asked to find an isomorphism between $M_{3\times 2}(F)$ and $P_5(F)$, but what does it mean for a $3\times 2$ matrix to have an inverse?

Comment: They don't have inverses.  Inverses don't apply in this problem.  The isomorphism $M_{3 \times 2}(F) \to P_5(F)$ is just a *linear* isomorphism.  It has noting to do with multiplication of matrices.

Comment: @Jim I see. So what is meant by *linear* here?

Comment: Respects addition and scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

As vector spaces over $F$, $\dim M_{3\times 2}(F)=\dim P_5(F)=6$. Indeed, we have bases
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &= \{E_{ij}:1\leq i\leq 3,1\leq j\leq 2\} \\
\beta  &= \{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5\}
\end{align}
$$
for  $M_{3\times 2}(F)$ and $P_5(F)$ respectively (here, $E_{ij}$ is the $3\times 2$ matrix whose entries are all zero except for the entriy $(i,j)$ whose entry is $1$). So, we may define a linear isomorphism $T: M_{3\times 2}(F)\rightarrow P_5(F)$ by defining
$$
\begin{align}
T(E_{11}) &= 1   & T(E_{12}) &= x \\
T(E_{21}) &= x^2 & T(E_{22}) &= x^3 \\
T(E_{31}) &= x^4 & T(E_{32}) &= x^5
\end{align}
$$
and extending linearly.

Comment: What does $T$ look like?

Comment: I don't follow...

Comment: $T\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\\e&f\end{smallmatrix}\right)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4+fx^5$ in @Brian's solution.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick So $T$ is $\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$, correct?

Comment: It depends how you view the ordering of the two bases. There are many ways to represent a linear transformation as a matrix.